# how to add comment on google sheet cell using google sheet api in node js?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet and i need to add comment on google sheet cell using google sheet api in node js. i tried some examples but that example add note on cell not add comment on cell.

also i tried addComment property but it doesn't work.it’s give me error like this:

```
 message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "addComment" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.`
```

```
await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      spreadsheetId: req.body.spreadsheetId,
      resource: {
        requests: [
          {
            updateCells: {
              range: {
                sheetId: mainSheetId,
                startRowIndex: 0,
                endRowIndex: 1,
                startColumnIndex: 0,
                endColumnIndex: 1
              },
              rows: [
                {
                  values: [
                    {
                      note: "sample note"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              fields: "note"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    })
```

i tried above example but it will add note on cell not add comment on cell. so how to add comment on cell ????